# Best way to move $100k+ from France to US?

Tags: usa, france, money-transfer, real-estate

I'm planning a real estate purchase in the US and will need to move $100k+ from multiple accounts I own in France to the US. Can someone advise on the best way to do this to minimize fees and delays?

- Should I consolidate the EUR accounts in France first before making one big transfer into USD? Or make separate transfers into the US?
- Should I just use my bank's international transfer service or is there a better way to transfer, like a company specializing in low cost foreign transfers?
- In the US, should I receive the funds in my bank first and then wire them to the escrow account for the real estate purchase, or should I wire directly from France into the US escrow account?
- Is there going to be a lot of paperwork involved? The France accounts are in my name and have been declared on my US tax returns for years already.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: This would seem to be a question for your bank and your real estate agent. See also https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/international-money-transfer-online-from-a-french-bank

Comment: If I were in your shoes I'd ask the lawyer handling my real estate transaction about the third bullet point.  It probably doesn't matter, and wiring directly would reduce the total cost, but your lawyer can tell you for sure.

Comment: [What is the cheapest way to send large amounts of money from EU to US?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/1154/164)

Comment: Professionals (bank, agents, etc.) involved in this transaction have zero international transaction experience

Comment: Consolidate, and wire (SWIFT) in local currency (EUR). The recipient bank typically converts cheaper.